# C# to Powershell InvokeMember

Tags: c#, powershell

How would I write the following C# code in Powershell?

```
m_object.GetType().InvokeMember(sPropertyName, m_flgGetProperty, null, m_object, null)
```

Comment: I am working on a PowerShell script. I am trying to get to a ChildObject from an Object. I tried multiple ways and researched for roughly 4 hours by now. The line above is in fact a result of my research. I is from a DispatchObject that I use in C# to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish in Powershell. I did look into InvokeMember in PS, but couldn't find a way to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost exactly the same way you do in C#. For example, this is how you would get the `Length` property from a string (if for some reason you had to do it this way):

```
$m_object = "some string"
$sPropertyName = "Length"
$m_flgGetProperty = [Reflection.BindingFlags] "DeclaredOnly, Public, NonPublic, Instance, GetProperty"

$m_object.GetType().InvokeMember($sPropertyName, $m_flgGetProperty, $null, $m_object, $null)
```

The differences from C#:

1. Variables all start with `$`.
2. Refer to types with their full namespace (although `System` is not needed), enclosed in `[]`.
3. To combine enum flags into a single value (like for the `BindingFlags`), you can use the comma-separated list like above instead of `|`. PowerShell converts the strings into the enum values for you.

Comment: This solved my problem. I adjusted the BindingFlags and used an object for $m_object.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell natively allows for dynamic invocation to a degree, so assuming the type member is *public*, it might be as simple as:

```bsh
$PropertyName = 'MemberName'
$object.$PropertyName
```

Comment: In my scenario with the Sage 100 COM objects, this approach didn't work.